# Android Emulator 5.1 issue - Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

**I'm asking this question to find out if someone has the same problem, because the API 22 is new and I don't know if the problem is related to this fact or I have some other issue on my system.**

I have just installed new Android 5.1 emulator and I'm unable to install any application on it.

Console:

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
>   ...

LogCat:

> Unable to open/data/dalvik-cache/. to delete it's contents: Permission denied
>   ...

AVD Configuration:

[image]

## Edit:

After a couple of restarts of Eclipce and AVD it's working fine now. Don't know where was the problem.